# Java generics put String or Integer argument in method

Tags: java, generics

I want to make something like this. How I can do this pretty in java with generics?

```
 public <T [Integer or String]> Float getFloat(<T> column) throws SQLException{
    Float result;

    try {
        result = ResultSet.getFloat(column);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        result = null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now my code looks like this:

```
public Float getFloat(String column) throws SQLException{
    Float result;

    try {
        result = rs.getFloat(column);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        result = null;
    }
    return result;
}
public Float getFloat(int column) throws SQLException{
    Float result;
    try {
        result = rs.getFloat(column);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        result = null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I do this because method rs.getFloat() may receive String (Column label) & Integer (Column Index) only. But this not important for my method.

Comment: It would be possible to use lambdas: `public <T> Float getFloat(Function<T,Float> function, T t) ` but because of JDBC's checked exceptions it won't be much fun to do that,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't seem like a good use case for generics, IMO. Both `String` and `Integer` are final classes so there are only 2 possibilities here. Seems like it would just be easier to overload the method.

You can bound a generic like `<T extends A & B>` but I have found no capability to use `|` operator for this kind of bounding.